# Book title request (yellow acid, aliens, cultural denial of life cycle)

Tags: story-identification

I read a book somewhere around a decade ago (the book itself may have been quite a bit older). I only remember fragments of it but there were aliens that denied part of their biology and had developed a tradition of shunning and letting die members that where transforming into their next life cycle stage.

One part that sticks with me is apparently when mutating they became something that secreted yellow acid that dissolved anything it touched and they would suck it back up and that's how they fed. There was some hidden giant mother form that was the end of the life cycle as well, that the humans in the story eventually meet.

I seem to remember the acid coming down in rain form at some point but I'm fuzzier on that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know the series of books your referring to. Check out the Species Imperative by Julie Czerneda: http://www.czerneda.com/sf/species.html

Comment: You could add some snippets or summaries to prove that this is actually the book series OP is looking for.

Comment: Damn, that's it! Didn't expect an answer after this long. Thanks.